# SQL syntax for same column from a table being used at 2 different places in the data entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm having a hard time trying to retrieve a field which is used at 2 different places in the data entry system.

My current SQL query (extract shown further below) use 3 tables:

(1) dbo.TravelAgency

```
**Company           TravelAgencyId   CountryCode**
  ABC Ltd               734             SE
  TOM Co. Ltd           620             CZ
```

(2) dbo.Market

```
 **CountryCode      CountryName         CountryGroup**
   SE                Sweden              Scandinavia
   CZ                Czech Republic      Central Europe
```

(3) dbo.ReservationStay

```
**Name    TaProfileID1     TaProfileID2** 
  John        734              620
```

My SQL Query stands like this:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT ......,
       .......,
       e.Company AS 'Tour Operator',
       c.TaProfileID1,
       ................,
       g.countryGroup AS 'Market'
       ................
FROM GuestNameInfo a
     ................................
     LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelagencyID = c.TaProfileID1
     LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
```

When I run this query, I get the following:

```
Name     Tour Operator    TaProfileID1    Market
John     ABC Ltd            734           Scandinavia
```

I now need to add the TaProfileID2 in the query so that my output becomes:

```
Name     Tour Operator    TaProfileID1      Market         Market 2
John       ABC Ltd            734           Scandinavia     Central Europe
```

How do I add a "JOIN" to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just JOIN onto the same tables again with a different alias:

```
SELECT ......,
       .......,
       e.Company AS 'Tour Operator',
       c.TaProfileID1,
       ................,
       g.countryGroup AS 'Market'
       g2.countryGroup AS 'Market 2'
       ................
FROM GuestNameInfo a
     ................................
     LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelagencyID = c.TaProfileID1
     LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
     LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelagencyID = c.TaProfileID2
     LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode2 = g2.CountryCode
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I messed the syntax. Just edited and updated accordingly. c is for ReservationStay. a is for GuestNameInfo

Comment: @user3115933 Doesn't really matter, then answer basically remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to join through `dbo.TravelAgency` and into `dbo.Market` twice - once for the role of `TaProfileID1` and once for `TaProfileID2`.

Since the join through TravelAgency and Market seem to be common to both (and probably other) joins, why not wrap these in a view or common table expression, e.g.

```
WITH cteTaMarket AS
(
  SELECT ta.Name, ta.TravelAgencyId, m.CountryGroup AS Market
   FROM TravelAgency ta 
   LEFT JOIN Market m ON ta.CountryCode = m.CountryCode
)
SELECT rs.Name, tm1.Name as TourOperator, tm1.ProfileID AS TaProfileID1, 
       tm1.MarketName as Market, tm2.MarketName as Market2
FROM ReservationStay rs
     INNER JOIN cteTaMarket tm1 ON tm1.TravelagencyID = rs.TaProfileID1
     INNER JOIN cteTaMarket tm2 ON tm2.TravelagencyID = rs.TaProfileID2;
```